# Depth of atoms in list

Tags: list, scheme, depth

I am trying to find depth of each element in a list and simultaneously create a output where flattened output is written with their depth level , so far i came up with following logic -

```
(define nestingDepth
 (lambda (lst1)
    (cond ((null? lst1) 1) 
          ((list? (car lst1)) 
          (cons(+ 1(nestingDepth (car lst1)))) (nestingDepth (cdr lst1)))          
          ((null? (cdr lst1)) (cons (1 (cdr lst1))) (nestingDepth (cdr lst1))))))
```

But this is not printing anything in output. Please update where i am going wrong.
Expected result will look like -
input - '(a (b) c)
output - (1 a 2 b 1 c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some other answers have mentioned, it's important to make sure that each case retursn something of the proper type.  If the input is the empty list, then the output should be the empty list.  If the input is a pair, then you need to handle the car and the cdr of the pair and connect them.  If the input is neither the empty list nor a pair, then the result is a list of the depth and the input.

Now, it may be handy to build the result incrementally.  You can build from the right to the left, and add each element and its depth using an approach like the following:

```
(define (depths tree)
  (let depths ((tree tree)
               (depth 0)
               (results '()))
    (cond
      ((null? tree) results)
      ((pair? tree) (depths (car tree)
                            (+ 1 depth)
                            (depths (cdr tree)
                                    depth
                                    results)))
      (else (cons depth (cons tree results))))))
```

```
> (depths '(a ((b) c ((d))) e))
(1 a 3 b 2 c 4 d 1 e)
```

Comment: `(depths '(a . b))` yields `'(1 a 0 b)`. It that correct?

Comment: Op did not specify what should happen with improper lists. B is not an element of the top-level list, so it's not really at any depth within. I don't think that it is unreasonable for its depth to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution (I have changed the output format a little to make the solution easier to code). `append-map` is defined in [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html).

```
(define (depths x)
  (cond ((list? x)
         (append-map (lambda (y)
                       (map (lambda (z)
                              (cons (car z) (+ (cdr z) 1)))
                            (depths y)))
                     x))
        (else `((,x . 0)))))
```

(I write the code as a seasoned Schemer would write it, not as someone would write a homework assignment. If that's your situation, try to understand what my code does, then reformulate it into something homework-acceptable.)

Answer (score 1):

All the previous solutions work well for proper (nested) lists, for those who work for improper lists I am not sure if they are correct.

For example, `(depths '(a . b))` yields `(1 a 0 b)` for Joshua's, and `(((a . b) . 0))` for Chris', but I'd say it should be `(1 a 1 b)`.

I'd therefore go for

```
(define (depths sxp)
  (let loop ((sxp sxp) (res null) (level (if (cons? sxp) 1 0)))
    (cond
      ((null? sxp) res)
      ((pair? sxp) (let ((ca (car sxp)))
                     (loop ca
                           (loop (cdr sxp) res level)
                           (if (pair? ca) (add1 level) level))))
      (else        (cons level (cons sxp res))))))
```

and my test cases are:

```
(check-equal? (depths '(a . b)) '(1 a 1 b))
(check-equal? (depths 'a) '(0 a)) ; 0
(check-equal? (depths '(a)) '(1 a))
(check-equal? (depths '(a a)) '(1 a 1 a))
(check-equal? (depths '(a (b . c) d (e (f (g h . i) . j)))) '(1 a 2 b 2 c 1 d 2 e 3 f 4 g 4 h 4 i 3 j))

(check-equal? (depths '(a (b) c)) '(1 a 2 b 1 c))
(check-equal? (depths '(a ((b) c ((d))) e)) '(1 a 3 b 2 c 4 d 1 e))
(check-equal? (depths '(a (b (c (d e))) f g)) '(1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 4 e 1 f 1 g))
```

Answer (score 0):

The base case is wrong (you can't return `1` if you intend to output a list as a result), the way the recursion is being advanced doesn't build a list as output … a complete rewrite is needed; the following solution is portable and should work on any Scheme interpreter, making use only of basic procedures:

```
(define (nestingDepth lst)
  (let depth ((lst lst) (n 1))
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((not (pair? (car lst)))
           (cons n
                 (cons (car lst)
                       (depth (cdr lst) n))))
          (else
           (append (depth (car lst) (+ 1 n))
                   (depth (cdr lst) n))))))
```

The output is as expected:

```
(nestingDepth '(a (b (c (d e))) f g))
=> '(1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 4 e 1 f 1 g)
```